# Using gensim's Phraser with pre-trained vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, phrase

I am trying to use pre-trained word embeddings taking into account phrases. Popular pre-trained embeddings like `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` have separate embeddings for phrases as well as unigrams e.g., embeddings for `New_York` and the two unigrams `New` and `York`. Naive word tokenization and dictionary look-up ignore the bigram embedding.

Gensim provides a nice [Phrase](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) model, where given a text sequence it can learn compact phrases e.g., `New_York` instead of two unigrams `New` and `York`. This is done by aggregating and comparing count statistics between the  unigrams and the bigram. 1. Is it possible to use `Phrase` with pre-trained embeddings without estimating the count statistics elsewhere?

1. Is it possible to use `Phrase` with pre-trained embeddings without estimating the count statistics elsewhere?
2. If not, is there an efficient way to use these bigrams? I can imagine a way using a loop, but I believe it is ugly (Below).

Here is the ugly code.

```
from ntlk import word_tokenize
last_added = False
sentence = 'I love New York.'
tokens =  ["<s>"]+ word_tokenize(sentence) +"<\s>"]
vectors = []
for index, token in enumerate(tokens):
    if last_added:
        last_added=False
        continue
    if "%s_%s"%(tokens[index-1], token) in model:
        vectors.append("%s_%s"%(tokens[index-1], token))
        last_added = True
    else:
        vectors.append(tokens[index-1])
        lase_added = False
```